# Can't shutdown a process in a user session from a service

Tags: windows, service, process, signals

The architecture is a service can start a process within a process group in a user session with system privilege, code snippet 1.

When the service needs to stop itself, I want to send a signal to the child process to give it a chance to shut down gracefully, code snippet 2.

The problem is it doesn't seem to send the signal at all without any obvious error code. I have tested the child process running from a command prompt, ctrl+break works just fine.

**code snippet 1**

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
ZeroMemory(&processInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

STARTUPINFO si;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
si.lpDesktop = "winsta0\\Default";
si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

LPVOID environment;
BOOL createRet = CreateEnvironmentBlock(&environment, userToken, FALSE);
if (!createRet) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create environment block");
}

DWORD creationFlags =
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS |
    CREATE_NO_WINDOW |
    CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT |
    CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP; // this create a process in a group

// launch a process in the user session
// the toke is a system privilege toke within the user session
createRet = CreateProcessAsUser(
    userToken, NULL, LPSTR(command.c_str()),
    sa, NULL, TRUE, creationFlags,
    environment, NULL, &si, &processInfo);

if (!createRet) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create the service in user session");
}

m_serviceGroupId = processInfo.dwProcessId;

DestroyEnvironmentBlock(environment);
CloseHandle(userToken);
```

**code snippet 2**

```
if (m_serviceGroupId == 0) {
    return;
}

HANDLE process;
const UINT kExitCode = 0;
const UINT kShutdownTimeout = 3000;
if (findProcessInSession(kServiceProcess, &process, getActiveSession())) {
    BOOL r = GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_BREAK_EVENT, m_serviceGroupId);
    // this won't success if I don't specifically call AllocConsole() in the constructor
    if (!r) {
        writeEventErrorLog(GetLastErrorAsString().c_str());
    }

    DWORD exitCode = WaitForSingleObject(process, kShutdownTimeout);
    if (exitCode != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
        // always fall into forceful shutdown
        writeEventErrorLog("Forcefully shutdown synergy service");
        // GetLastErrorAsString returns empty string
        writeEventErrorLog(GetLastErrorAsString().c_str());
        if (!TerminateProcess(process, kExitCode)) {
            writeEventErrorLog("Failed to shutdown synergy service");
        }
    }
}

m_serviceGroupId = 0;
```

Comment: `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` do remote call into `csrss`. but your service attached to another `csrss` process - every session have it own `csrss`. so `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` can not be used for send control event in another session

Comment: @RbMm Thank you. Is there any way I manage the child process? RPC call?

Comment: All you need to do is send a one-shot message from the service to the child, so a named event object would probably be the most suitable choice.  In more complex situations you might use a named pipe.  There are other options too.

Comment: `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` requests the console (i.e. conhost.exe) to request the session's Windows server (i.e. csrss.exe) to send a control event (Ctrl+C or Ctrl+break) to other processes that are attached to the same console, filtered by process group, which it does by creating a thread in each target process that starts at `kernelbase!CtrlRoutine`. Attaching to a console is limited to processes in the same session as the console. Moreover, a service isn't even run with an attached console, i.e. the service controller creates service processes with the flag `DETACHED_PROCESS`.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach doesn't work because service process and child process are not in the same session, so consider Windows events instead. Have a look at [CreateEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396(v=vs.85).aspx) and [SetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686211(v=vs.85).aspx).

When your service process starts, call CreateEvent(), for example:

```
HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, "Global\\myevent");
```

When your child process starts, call CreateEvent(), and start a thread to capture the signal:

```
//The lpName should be identical with that in service process
HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, "Global\\myevent");

std::thread mythread([hEvent] {
    WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
    //then exit your child process gracefully
});
```

Whenever you intend to stop the child process, just call SetEvent() in your service process:

```
SetEvent(hEvent);
```

Set bManualReset to TRUE, then your service can send signal to different child processes simultaneously.